# Values of a book saved from amazon have {:value=>""} around it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making an application where the user can search Amazon (with Vacuum) through my application for books, then be able to record the data of the book to their library.

When you search for a book, it goes through every result and puts each in a thumbnail. In every thumbnail there is a button that opens a modal with a form with hidden tags. When the user clicks the submit button, the book's title is saved into a new book. The only problem is that the title is saved like `{:value=>"the title of the book that was saved"}`

Here is the part of new.html.erb which has the search box:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "books", action: "new"}, method: "get", id: "search-form") do %>
          <%= text_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords], placeholder: "Search for a book", class: "form-control" %>
        <% end %>
```

Here is the part of new.html.erb which has the hidden form:

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  …
<%= form_for @book do |f|%>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag :title, class: 'form-control', value: result.name %>

                    <%= f.submit "Add book", class: "btn btn-default green-hover" %>

                <% end %>
    …
    <% end %>
```

Here are the new and create actions in my controller:

```
def new
    @book = current_user.books.build if logged_in?

    # Search actions
    if params[:keywords]
        request = Vacuum.new

    request.configure(
      aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      associate_tag: 'my associate tag is here'
    )
    keywords = params[:keywords]
    params = {
      'SearchIndex' => 'Books',
      'Keywords'=> keywords,
      'ResponseGroup' => "ItemAttributes,Images"
    }

    raw_results = request.item_search(query: params)
    hashed_results = raw_results.to_h

    @results = []

    hashed_results['ItemSearchResponse']['Items']['Item'].each do |item|
      result = OpenStruct.new
      result.title = item['ItemAttributes']['Title']
      result.url = item['DetailPageURL']
      result.image_url = item['MediumImage']['URL']
      result.author = item['ItemAttributes']['Author']
      result.pages = item['ItemAttributes']['NumberOfPages']
      @results << result 
    end
  end
end

def create
    @book = @list.books.build(book_params)
    if @book.save
        flash[:success] = @book.title + "was added to your log."
        redirect_to list_path(@book.list_id)
    else
        render 'books/new'
    end
end
```

I tried to use gsub within `book.rb` to fix it, but that only changed the text within the flash message and it still saved as  `{:value=>"the title of the book that was saved"}`.

```
after_create :init

private
def init
  puts "Init was called!"
  self.title.gsub!('{:value=>"', " ")
  self.title.gsub!('"}', " ")
end
```

How can I change it so that it doesn't save the title with the `{:value=>}` around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the hidden field tag is right.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :title, class: 'form-control', value: result.name %>
```

Try

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :title, result.name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title is being saved as a [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html) not a string. Use hash accessing methods:

```
t = title[:value]
puts t #=> "the tile of the book that was saved"
```